# Java: Save to a file online

Tags: java, writetofile

Currently, I have this:

```
String URL = "//Somewhere in my computer";
PrintWriter list = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(URL, true));
```

Is it possible to write to an online site that has document? For example, there are sites where you only need the URL of the site to write in that document. Is it possible to read and edit such from an java program?

This is what I did for a TitanPad Service:

```
String someText = "Here goes magical text";

    URL url = null;
    try {
        url = new URL("https://titanpad.com/3VBeN3Xo31");
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    URLConnection connection = null;
    try {
        connection = url.openConnection();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    connection.setDoOutput(true);

    OutputStream outStream = null;
    try {
        outStream = connection.getOutputStream();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        outStream.write(someText.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    try {
        outStream.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
```

Comment: Yes, but you have to change the interface / protocol. There are several ways to do that, e.g. a HTTP Client, (S)FTP Client, SSH... It is more a matter of protocol you want / have to use. Bear in mind that in some cases you need to allow or even implement reading / writing / authentication functionalities on the target (URL) server as well.
I have the feeling you need a better understanding on which protocol to use and then detail your request. (e.g. "I want to read/write a file from/to URL using Apache HTTP client).
Your question is too much generic and may lead to different interpretations.

Comment: @medveshonok117 Sounds very complicated. Are you sure there are no easy/smooth way of doing this? Any online service that is somehow built to work with java?

Comment: Accepted answer is an example of what I was talking about (FTP). So, it doesn't sound very complicated at all. But that means the server must accept FTP connections and you are allowed to do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use FTP-

```
String someText = "Here goes magical text";

URL url = new URL("ftp://user:password@somewebsite.com/filename.txt");
URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();

connection.setDoOutput(true);

OutputStream outStream = connection.getOutputStream();

outStream.write(someText.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8"))); 
outStream.close();
```

Comment: I received over 50 errors. I changed the URL to a "TitanPad" online service. How will I make it work if so?

Comment: @Playdowin If you have permission and user/pass for ftp access, can you please share the 'error' messages?

Comment: `javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
 at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)`
 ... etc

Comment: @Playdowin Maybe you can add your server certificate to the trusted certificates list of your JVM.

Comment: If you don't know how - http://magicmonster.com/kb/prg/java/ssl/pkix_path_building_failed.html

Comment: I understand. Its quite complicated.. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Playdowin It's not so complicated. Give it a try. :)